# Is it appropriate to put polyethylene between hardwood and subfloor?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood

My installer put polyethylene between hardwood and subfloor. Is that a problem?

Comment: Depends on what the subfloor is, what level of the home we're talking about, what your climate is, what the flooring is.... Please revise with more detail.

Comment: sub floor is plywood -  main level with framed basement-   southern on ca     home has an erv  this is a brand new energy star  home

Comment: Please *revise* to add more detail.

Comment: Is it a nail down or floating installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a moisture barrier. See  
[Moisture Barrier and Underlayments: Don’t Leave It Out!](https://www.lumberliquidators.com/blog/moisture-barrier-and-underlayments-dont-leave-it-out/)  for a little more explanation. However, in your case that appears to have been an unnecessary expense. I doubt it would hurt anything except your wallet.

Comment: Given the new information in the comment above, from where are we barricading moisture, exactly?

Comment: @isherwood You are correct. Which means either (a) the installer is an idiot or (b) the installer wanted to be able to charge for installation of the moisture barrier despite the moisture barrier being effectively useless. I vote for (b), but I have become skeptical in my old age.

Comment: To be fair, it's standard practice to put some sort of sheet between the layers of wood for noise abatement. Maybe that's the intention. Typically it's rosin paper, but who knows?

Comment: @isherwood Noise abatement?? What STC rating is one layer of paper?

Comment: We use rosin paper for a allow two materials to slip past each other. See   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_rosin_paper

Comment: Seems you answered your own question there. It's essentially a lubricant between the two layers of wood to minimize squeaks and creaks.

Comment: I would actually ask the installer why - there could be many good reasons dreamt up. But it does sound like a waste. Did they write it up as polyethelyne on the ticket? They did the job, so they may have a solid idea.